# Drupal with Texy and GeSHi

Tags: drupal, module

I have my Drupal installation set up to use both [Texy](http://drupal.org/project/texy) for markup (hand-writing HTML soon gets tedious) and [GeSHi](http://drupal.org/project/geshifilter) for syntax highlighting (which is about the only syntax highlighter I found for Drupal at that time).

The problem now is that since the last update to Texy seemingly nothing really works anymore. I spend a long time trying to convince both of them working together a while ago but it was a pretty flaky setup. Depending on the order of evaluation of both filters I either get no syntax highlighting or all, escaped HTML output, line breaks disappear or, sometimes, it can indeed work.

I am now at a point where it almost works again, but with exceptions. Ideally GeSHi would take care of the code, while Texy handles the rest, but that's not the case. The nice regular expression

```
[1–9][0–9]*[WDwd][1–9][0–9]*(\+[1–9][0–9]*)?
```

gets the part between the first two asterisks italicized, since Texy runs over that part as well. Which is unfortunate, since it changes the meaning of the regex.

Anyone out here who has insights of how to peroperly set up multiple filters for input in Drupal and how to handle non-HTML markup *and* syntax highlighting simultaneously. As I currently have to go over every post that contains code I have written (nearly all) it wouldn probably not much less work to completely redo every page on the site in search for a better setup. As for syntax highlighting, I have much need for the usual common languages, such as C#, Java, etc. but also for more esoteric ones like Windows batch files or Powershell. Simply dumping unhighlighted code there isn't very pretty.

So, actually I have two questions here:

1. How can one convince multiple input filters to work without interfering with each other, specifically Texy and GeSHI?
2. What other options are out there that meet my requirements of easy-to-write non-HTML markup<sup>1</sup> *and* syntax highlighting even for lesser-used languages<sup>2</sup>?

---

<sup>1</sup> Often I just need emphasis and strong emphasis, sometimes headings, often images, sometimes also tables. Oh, and usually code :-)

<sup>2</sup> The Stack Overflow-like guessing for syntax highlighting doesn't work very well for most code, it just works *well enough* to be a little pleasing.

Comment: is it belong to stack over flow ?

Comment: Erm, why does thi belong on SO? Heck, I don't want to *write* a Drupal module, I just want to get them to work *or* find solutions that have worked for others. This (ideally) shouldn't involve any programming. If anywhere I'd migrate this to serverfault, but then again, it's not exactly a server administration question.

Answer (score 0):

To answer **2.** I have had good results with markdown and GeSHI. I have no experience with Texy.

What you must pay very good attention to, is the combination of filter-format settings, filter-format ordering, filter-format permissions. For your problem, I would suggest the following input formats.

- Basic HTML (**default**). Used for comments and so on.
- Markdown (For editors, does what you describe)
- Raw HTML  (no filtering **at all** usefull for webmasters etc.)

Then configure them as follows, in this order:

- Basic HTML:

  - URL filter
  - HTML filter. only allow inline styles *em, strong, a*. Maybe a very few more, but not br, p and such.
  - linebreak filter.
- Markdown

  - HTML filter: strips *all* tags, except the "code" tags for GESHI.
  - Markdown filter.
  - Geshi filter.

This implies that markdown has no limits: people can use markdown to creat H1 tags, for example. If you want to limit the abilities in Markdown, you must place the HTML filter *after* the markdown filter. In that set-up, markdown will convert to full HTML, then the HTML-filters will strip the not-allowed filters. 
Since GeSHI requires non-standard `code` tags, you will want to let them fall-trough. Since GeSHI adds a bucketload of spans, divs and color-coded style-elements, you will always need to put this filter *after* the HTML-filter, to avoid these spans- etc to be removed again